# OpenEntityManagerInView is not working with JSF

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, jpa, lazy-loading

I have created sample project using JSF+Spring+JPA.
I have 2 entities Customer and Order where customer can have more than one order so mapping between Customer and Order is @OneToMany.
Customer Class is as below

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries
(
    {
        @NamedQuery(name=Contact.QUERY_FIND_ALL, query="FROM Contact"),
    }
)
public class Customer
    {
        public final static String QUERY_FIND_ALL="findAll";

        @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<Order> orders;

        public List<Order> getOrders() 
        {
            return orders;
        }

        public void setOrders(List<Order> orders) 
        {
            this.orders = orders;
        }
    }
```

My View works like below

**1st Case:**

1. We load all cutomer and display them on screen with and arrow in
   front of each record this happens in one request.
2. now when end-user click on arrow we want to display all order of
   that Customer.

   **but i am getting Lazy load exception even though i am using OpenEntityManagerInView.**

**2nd Case:**

1. If I load both Customer and Order in one request it work fine.

is there somthing like that if we load parent in one request we cant load its lazy association in second request?

why its not working in 1st case and working in second case?

and

**more important what is the other solution to archive it?**

Comment: `OpenSessionInViewFilter` only works for a single request as soon as your page is rendered the session is closed. Now when you click an arrow the original session isn't there anymore and as such lazy loading isn't working.

Comment: Thanks  M. Deinum but is there doc which says that we cannot use OpenEntityManagerInView across http request?

Comment: The javadoc of the mentioned class and the general notion that that is how open session in view works. What you want (more or less) is open view in conversation.

Answer (score 0):

When you load customer on your data access layer class (e.g CustomerDAO) you have to get at least one of each child property to bypass lazy proxy, maybe it would look like this

```
public class CustomerDAO{

       public Customer getCustomer(String custId){
            Customer cust = //your method to retrieve customer
            List<Order> orders = cust.getOrders();
            for(Order ord:orders){
                  ord.getOrderName(); // you have to get at least one of each child property to bypass lazy proxy
            }
       }
    }
```

Hope it would help